# docker-swarm - ip address eth0 shows more than one address

Tags: networking, docker-swarm

I'm using docker 1.12.1 in swarm mode.

When I run the following command:
`docker network create   --driver overlay   --subnet 10.0.9.0/24   --opt encrypted   services`
and then
`docker service create --name nginx nginx`

than exec the command `ip address` in the running container (on the correct node) the result is

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
234: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1424 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:0a:00:09:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.9.3/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.9.2/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:aff:fe00:903/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
236: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.3/16 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe12:3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Can please anyone explain, why eth0 has in that case two ip addresses `10.0.9.3/24` and `10.0.9.2/32`?

This causes a problem, because when I run more instances, there are overlapping addresses which breaks my running service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is VIP, used for service.

Another is for node address, only for internal use. From perspective of APP, they should use service IP.